# How to check if user is multi or single currency?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

Is there any way to distinguish between single and multi currency QBO user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the details here-
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/020_key_concepts/currency

You need to query Preferences endpoint-

```
<Preferences domain="QBO" sparse="false">
<Id>1</Id>
 ...
<TaxPrefs>
    <UsingSalesTax>false</UsingSalesTax>
</TaxPrefs>
<CurrencyPrefs>
    <MultiCurrencyEnabled>true</MultiCurrencyEnabled>
    <HomeCurrency>AUD</HomeCurrency>
</CurrencyPrefs>
  ...
</Preferences>
```